# Filter result on property always return empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I am stuck since this morning on an elasticsearch query. I want to query all objects that have their attributes **attr** equals to **value**. Here is what I tried but the output is empty althought these objects exists

```js
"query":
{
    "bool": {
      "must": {
          "match": {
            "attr": "value"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to retrieve all my object using the following query and it worked

```js
"query":
{
    "bool": {
      "must": {
          "match": {
            "_all": {}
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Please, Anyone can tell me why my query always return empty?

I am using elasticsearch 6.5.

Comment: What if you don't have the bool must ? I think {query:{match: {attr: val}} will suffice.

Comment: Actually I use bool because I will add a filtering clause, I removed it to keep the post simpler. Howerever  {query:{match: {attr: val}} still return and empty set

Comment: I finally solve the problem. thanks for your assistance

Comment: The problem was not my query but my indexing process failed. Only empty documents (only their identifiers) where saved.

Comment: Wasn't much help but I am glad you solved your problem.